# JTable Column modelIndex vs viewIndex

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable where I can reorder the columns in the GUI. Moreover, I use the following API's:

```
Component javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)

Component javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
```

They all take a parameter "column", which is the columnIndex. My question now is, what does Swing assume? Does it assume the column index of the **model** or the column index of the **view**?

I Hope I have stated the question clearly enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JTable is the `View`, so code found in the table methods will be the view value. This is also true for the row values.